# How to update the libusb driver using the INF file on device manager

Tags: device-driver, cdc, inf, device-manager, libusbdotnet

I am developing a program for communicate between device and pc with libusbdotnet dll.The device uses CDC(Communication Device Class) in USB classes.

I created an INF file from libusbdotnet inf wizard. And I updated driver with inf files on device manager. But on some computers inf file can not update. And give this error : "*The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software driver for your device. If the folder contains a driver, make sure it is designed to work with Windows for x64-based systems.*"

But some 64 bit computers(W7,W8 or W10) accept the inf file. So it doesn't seem about operating system or system type.

I tried a lot of solution method about this error from some sources.But I didn't find correct solution.

What do you think about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did yo try to update other usb drivers on the system of failed computer? Some Windows operating systems don't recognize the custom usb drivers, so when you update other generic usb drivers, the problem can be solved.